# Assignment to global vs local variables of different types in Python

Tags: python, global-variables

In the code below, I understand that inside the `change_my_var()` function, `my_var` is a local variable and so assignment to `my_var` would not change the global `my_var`.

However, that is not the case for `my_dict` (of dict type) and `my_list` (of list type). They change after `change_my_dict()` and `change_my_list()` are run. What should be the explanation behind?

```
my_dict = {}
my_list = []
my_var = None

def main():
    print('my_dict')
    print('before : ', my_dict)
    change_my_dict()
    print('after : ', my_dict)

    print()
    print('my_list')
    print('before : ', my_list)
    change_my_list()
    print('after : ', my_list)

    print()
    print('my_var')
    print('before : ', my_var)
    change_my_var()
    print('after : ', my_var)

def change_my_dict():
    my_dict['a'] = 'b'

def change_my_list():
    my_list.append('c1')

def change_my_var():
    my_var = 10

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
my_dict
before :  {}
after :  {'a': 'b'}

my_list
before :  []
after :  ['c1']

my_var
before :  None
after :  None
```

Comment: In `my_dict['a'] = 'b'` you're not assigning to a global, but mutating the dict bound to the global name *my_dict*. Same goes for the list. Trying to find a dupe target for this, since there pretty much has to be one.

Comment: In that case, what datatype does this rule apply to? I could imagine set, list and dict would be applicable. Any other datatypes too?

Comment: Anything that you mutate in place. Assignment and mutating an object are different things in this context. `my_var = 10` binds a value to the name, be it global or local. `my_list.append('c1')` and such mutate the referenced object. You should read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: It's not a question of "data type", it's about the difference between mutating an object's state and rebinding a variable. Try rebiding `my_dict` or `my_list` in your functions instead of mutating them and you'll find out...